# Displaying username logged in using thymeleaf fragment header in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a fragment for my web application which is used across multiple pages to display a navbar with the user logged in : if they are logged in, if not : display login & signup button.

I want to know how to include my attribute of a logged in user to a fragment as currently I have the logged in user attribute mapped to each controller displaying a web page, not a fragment.

To get the current logged in user I use

```
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", authentication.getName());
```

However this is only specific to one get request. I want to be able to display the logged in user in a fragment which is then called by each page.

Here is an example of a controller getting the logged in user

```
    @GetMapping(path= "")
    public String getMainPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", authentication.getName());
        model.addAttribute("roles", authentication.getAuthorities());
        return "mainpage";
    }
```

Here is my class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to authenticate a users username and password against one in the database

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        String userbyUsernameQuery = "select username, password, '1' as enabled from auth_user where username=?;";
        String rolebyUsernameQuery = "SELECT auth_user.username, auth_role.role_name as authority from auth_user\n" +
                "INNER JOIN auth_user_role ON auth_user.auth_user_id = auth_user_role.auth_user_id\n" +
                "INNER JOIN auth_role ON auth_role.auth_role_id = auth_user_role.auth_role_id\n" +
                "WHERE auth_user.username =?";

        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(userbyUsernameQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolebyUsernameQuery)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());


    }
```

The part of the navbarHeader fragment I want to change is this

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a th:href="@{/registration}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/login}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I want to display the logged in user if logged in & disable the sign up button. If not then display the log in button & signup button

Here is my mainpage page which displays the current user logged in and role which I want to move to the fragment so I do not need to add all the code in each controller & html page.

```
<div align="right" id="loggedIn" th:if="${loggedinuser != null}">
    <div style="margin: 10px"
         th:text="'Logged in as: '+${loggedinuser} + ' Role: ' +${roles}">

    </div>
</div>
```

The user class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User{

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    private String enabled;

    public User(String name, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this issue I basically utilize `ModelAttribute` which would be available across all the Presentation compilation. So your controller would like this

```
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(path= "hi")
    public String getMainPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        return "mainpage";
    }

    @GetMapping(path= "hello")
    public String getMainPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        return "helloPage";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("loggedinuser")
    public User globalUserObject() {
        // Add all null check and authentication check before using. Because this is global 
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", authentication.getName());
        model.addAttribute("roles", authentication.getAuthorities());
        // Create User pojo class
        User user = new User(authentication.getName(), Arrays.asList(authentication.getAuthorities()))
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now the object `loggedinuser` available for all the pages.

Comment: When I get the value of user expecting to see 'Admin' and role 'ADMIN' I see null and 0. When I get the value of authentication.getName() etc... it shows me the name admin. Why is this? 

Is it because my constructor in my User class for the implementation of authentication is empty?

    public User(String name, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    }  

My fields in User are:

private int id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String password;

Comment: Can you post your user class?

Comment: I added a user class to the original post

Comment: Changed the constructor argument. This should work.

Comment: Having an issue of incompatible types. Required : Collection <? extends GrantedAuthority> but 'asList' was inferred to List<T>:no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Collection<capture of ? extends GrantedAuthority> conforms to GrantedAuthority

Comment: My issue I feel isn't to do with the method itself I feel it is to do with the fact that I have controllers in different classes for different web pages. So when I use the "loggedin" model it doesn't call it from the controller  which has the method to create the logged in user, therefore returning null values. How can I call this method in other controllers to get the model attribute or is there an easier way as I have still not been able to call it.